# Must off-shell graviton field be symmetric?

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, quantum-gravity

In weak field expansion, one can expand the metric tensor in general relativity as

$$g_{\mu\nu}=\eta_{\mu\nu}+h_{\mu\nu}$$

where $\eta_{\mu\nu}$ is the Minkowski metric and $h_{\mu\nu}$ can be treated as an independent graviton excitation field. "On-shell" for the field means that $\partial^\mu h_{\mu\nu}=0$ and $\eta^{\mu\nu}h_{\mu\nu}=0$, since e.g. in on-shell scattering amplitudes the $h_{\mu\nu}$ is effectively being replaced by polarization tensor $\epsilon^\mu\epsilon^\nu$ for which these constraints hold. However, when we consider the field to be off-shell, we do not impose these constraints and generically $\partial^\mu h_{\mu\nu}\neq 0$ and $\eta^{\mu\nu}h_{\mu\nu}\neq 0$.

> I wonder, even though $h_{\mu\nu}$ started its life as a metric perturbation and was therefore symmetric, when we take it to be off-shell, does it make sense to consider the case of non-symmetric $h_{\mu\nu}\neq h_{\nu\mu}$? Or would that not make any sense?

Comment: Since the first equation holds, it is not possible to consider $h_{\mu\nu}$ with arbitrary symmetry, because this would destroy the symmetry properties of the metric.

Comment: Yes. If you need spin-2, then it must be carried by a symmetric tensor field, at least in the free field case. You can construct theories from the bottom-up, including, for instance, from antisymmetric tensor fields (but it won't have spin-2). See this old paper by Nieuwenhuizen - https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0550321373901946

Comment: Thanks for your replies and the reference!